# iOS: How do I configure my iAd account after I decided to change my app name and thus ultimately my bundle identifier?

Tags: ios, iad

**Scenario** = I created an app that I want to put into production. I also have created an App ID on my developer.apple.com account for that app **and** an iAd account that I believe was created using said App ID.

```
com.domainname.appname
```

**Issue** = I changed the name of my app and inso doing I got a new domain name for the new name.

**Problem** = Apple does not allow you to *edit* an existing App ID.

**Question** = How do I change my App ID?

```
com.newdomainname.newappname
```

**Comment/Question** = I know Apple says that it is impossible, therefore, can someone who has been through a name change like this before enlighten me with the **steps** necessary to accomplish an app name change and change the App ID as such to be concurrent with iAd and any other third party service I may be using with said App ID?

If I have to create a whole new App profile with Apple or whatever, that's fine. I just need to know the **steps** so I don't get anything wrong and fudge things up. If someone who has done this before can help me I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: There is no need to touch the app id for bundle id to rename the app. And please search. The list of related questions to the right already shows several topics covering this question.

Comment: Negative. It is a unique question. Read. "3) (important) I also created an iAd account using the identifier for my app." No question covers that.

Comment: As I said, you don't touch the app id. It's a trivial name change.

Comment: Inso changing the name I also bought a new domain name for the App name I chose. I would like to change the bundle id (app id) to my new domain 'com.newdomain.myapp' so that everything "looks pretty".

Comment: Then update your question with that need. Your question only states that you want to change the name. With that additional need I will reopen since it is no longer a duplicate.

Comment: Did you read my last comment?

Comment: Very well I shall change the name of the question.

Comment: You still need to update the actual question making it clear that you want to change the app id too. The body of your question still looks like a duplicate since you make no mention that you want to change the app id.